# Cross Domain iFrame auto height resizing

Tags: iframe, resize, height

I've been googling and looking at various options but could not seem to be able to find a perfect solution that works in what I'm attempting...so needing some help here.

**The situation/environment that I have is the following:**

1. Parent page (which has the iframe) - is on a different domain, and the only control I have is a portion of the body tag, where it is updated via an admin console using html/WYSIWG editor. No access to head tag or even hosting jscript in their domain.
2. Child page (iframe) - is hosted in our domain, and we have full control.

The parent site is actually 3rd party online stores where we have products there, and we want to put in common information that we can control on our end without having to edit each individual product listing one by one.

I've tried alot of options found but it does not seem to work as either they need to include in js file or access to the head tag in the parent page.

So wondering if there are any other options that can help us on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you need access to JavaScript on both domains to do this.

Could you get the 3rd online store to host a small JS library that all their clients could then use to solve this problem? I work on a project that allows third parties to add in iFrames and produced this little project for just this reason. When any one say they want to be able have their iFrame resize to content, we point to the iFrame js file and say include this on your page.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Sorry, that's not quite the answer your after, but trying asking the store to support this and they might be open to the idea, as I expect others have the same issue with their site.